# Javascript array search and filter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, array-filter

I want to create new array based on keyword.

if my search key word is

- "align-center" result should be  ["align-center"]
- "align" result should be  ["align-left", "align-center", "align-right"]
- "right" result should be  ["align-right"]
- "arrow" result should be  ["align-left", "align-right"]

```
const myarray = [
        {
            "align-center": [
                "align",
                "center"
            ]
        },
        {
            "align-justify": [
                "align",
                "justified"
            ]
        },
        {
            "align-left": [
                "align",
                "left",
                "arrow"
            ]
        },
        {
            "align-right": [
                "align",
                "right",
                "arrow"
            ]
        }
    ]

    let results = myarray.filter(function (name) { return  *****  
});
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: your result has an error.  if searching `arrow` result is [`align-left`, `align-right`], searching `align` result must contain  `align-justify` because `align-justify` object contains `align`

Comment: An array of objects each with a single, different key is generally a bad design. Why not have a single object with keys `align-center`, `align-justify`, etc.?

Comment: `filter` returns 0 or more elements from the given array, so none of your expected output fits that pattern. Therefore `filter` is not appropriate here.

Comment: Hint: Use `Object.keys(name)[0]` to get the key of the object. Then test if the keyword is in the key.

Comment: This is custom array so I can change array design @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `map()` to get the key of each object in the array. Then use `filter()` to return the ones that match the search string.

```js
let searchKey = 'left';

function search(array, searchKey) {
  return array.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0]).filter(key => key.includes(searchKey));
}

console.log(search(myarray, 'align-center'));
console.log(search(myarray, 'align'));
console.log(search(myarray, 'right'));
```

```html
<script>
  const myarray = [{
      "align-center": [
        "align",
        "center"
      ]
    },
    {
      "align-justify": [
        "align",
        "justified"
      ]
    },
    {
      "align-left": [
        "align",
        "left",
        "arrow"
      ]
    },
    {
      "align-right": [
        "align",
        "right",
        "arrow"
      ]
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object that represents the opposite relation:

```js
const myarray = [{"align-center": ["align","center"]},{"align-justify": ["align","justified"]},{"align-left": ["align","left","arrow"]},{"align-right": ["align","right","arrow"]}]

const transposed = myarray
    .flatMap(Object.entries)
    .flatMap(([key, values]) => values.map(value => [value, key]))
    .reduce((acc, [value, key]) => ((acc[value] ??= []).push(key), acc), {});

console.log(transposed);
```